# ¿Cómo evitar abrir/guardar de IE en contenido de un iframe de audio?

Tags: iframe, audio, ventana, internet-explorer-11

Cómo todos sabemos Chrome no autoriza el autoplay en audios/videos (salvo que esten silenciados: muted).
Estoy usando una solución que funciona perfecta, salvo por un pequeño detalle en Internet Explorer que les paso a comentar.

```
<iframe src="silence.ogg" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display:none"></iframe> 
        <audio id="player" autoplay controls><source src="https://url-shoutcast-radio.tk/mi_audio.mp3;" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Bien, lo que sucede en Internet Explorer es que muestra la opción de abrir o descargar el archivo "silence.ogg" (que es un archivo que tiene unos segundos de audio en silencio, sólo sirve para autorizar el autoplay en Chrome, del audio del "player").

Deseo evitar esta ventanita:

[image: Deseo evitar esta ventanita:]

Es a los meros efectos de no molestar con este tipo de ventanas al usuario, que obviamente no desea abrir o guardar nada, solo entra a escuchar música.
Además que le puede dar desconfianza de porque se le pregunta eso.

Saludos y gracias por la posible ayuda.

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado!!!

En lugar de usar `iframe` uso `embed` con esto logro ambos objetivos, permito el autoplay en chrome evitando el dialogo de IE.

```
<embed src="silence.ogg" type="audio/ogg" autostart="true" hidden="true">
```